# How to retrieve digital experience site after refreshing the sandbox

Tags: community-builder, experience-cloud

We created a community site in the lower environment and later we refreshed that sandbox and now we don’t have access to that community site we created, is there a way we can retrieve that community site?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can restore the metadata of the community after refresh, [source control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) like GIT is a must; use it from next time.

Answer (score 2):

If you contact Support, they may be able to roll back the refresh. You have somewhere between 24-48 hours after a completed refresh to contact Support and roll back the refresh before the previous version of the Sandbox is permanently deleted. If it's been more than 48 hours, recovery will likely be impossible. As Raul says, it is prudent to back up your metadata in a code repository to avoid this problem in the future.